# Checking if an attribute matches a lookup table

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a point file representing plants (Species 1, Species 2, etc.) and a polygon file of ecozones (Zone A, Zone B, etc.). I also have a lookup table for which zones each plant species is known to grow in, which looks like:

Species A, Zone 1
Species A, Zone 2
Species A, Zone 3
Species B, Zone 2
Species B, Zone 3
Species B, Zone 4
etc.

My goal is to determine whether or not each plant point is inside a zone it is known to grow in. By using a spatial join, I am able to apply the zone code to each point, but how can I relate this value to the lookup table to determine whether the zone assigned is in the lookup table? Is there something I should be doing before the spatial join?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is an example of a many-to-many relationship i.e. each zone can have many species, and each species can occur in many zones.

The functionality to work with many-to-many relationships in ArcGIS for Desktop is the Relationship Class, and how that is done can be read about in the ArcGIS Online Help under **[An overview of creating and maintaining relationship classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004t00000006000000)**.

Unfortunately, even when working with File Geodatabases, you require a Standard or Advanced level license before you can create a relationship class.

If you have a Basic license level, then there are workarounds to be able to deal with many-to-many relationships, but if they are available to you, then I think you should consider creating a relationship class first.